# How to display the data came from controller/model using Ajax process?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem here about ajax. Actually I'm a beginner in using Ajax that's why I can't figure out my problem. I have a form that have 4 select boxes. The initial or main selectbox is the country selector. Second is the state next is city and last is barangay. My goal is like this. After the user select his'her country the second selectbox which is state will automatically change according to the user's country. And after selecting the state it will automatically change also the city and last is the barangay. It is just like a dynamic address fields. I am using codeigniter. Here's what I did. This is the process for getting the state.

In my PHP form I have this:

```
<tr>
    <td><label style="font-weight: normal">State / Province:&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td >
        <select class="form-control" name="c_state" id="c_state">
            <option value="">--Select State--<option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label style="font-weight: normal">Country:&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td >
        <select class="form-control" name="c_country" id="c_country">
            <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
            <?php
                foreach($countries as $country){
                    if($country['country'] == 'Philippines'){
                        echo "<option value='".$country['code']."'selected='selected'>".$country['country']."</option>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<option value='".$country['code']."'>".$country['country']."</option>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

....

$("#c_country").on('change',function(){

    var c_country = $("#c_country").val();
    var var_country_selection = '<?php echo site_url("alliance_controller/get_provinces/'+c_country+'"); ?>';

    console.log(c_country);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: var_country_selection,
        data: { id: $(this).val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d){
            alert(d['c_country']);
        }
    });

});
```

In my controller I have this:

```
public function get_provinces($id){
     $country = $this->alliance_model->hhj_provinces($id);
     echo json_decode($country);
}
```

In my model I have this:

```
public function hhj_provinces($id) {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM ref_region_province WHERE  country_code = '".$id."'";
     $result = $this->db->query($query);
     echo json_encode($result->result_array());
}
```

The output in the success in jquery which is in alert is 'undefined'. And I also use the developer tool in Chrome and I looked in the Network tab it shows the URL of my ajax together the Code. But in my preview I have something like this.

```
[]
No Properties
```

That's all guys. I just want to get the state of the country selected.

Comment: did you check if the query returned any results?

Comment: no it doesn't show anything.

Comment: so if the query doesn't return any results, you will get `[]` as your output.

Comment: try running this `SELECT * FROM ref_region_province WHERE  country_code = '".$id."'` with one of the selected ids  on your db and see if you're getting any results

Comment: ok i will try your suggestion.

Comment: Ok the query is running the output from my browser is like this.

`{id:11, region_code:101, destination:Autonomous Region in Muslim Mindanao (ARMM), state_id:644,…}`

Comment: Ok I already found out my error. Sorry for my mistake. In my database the country that has states are United States and Philippines the others are none that's why I got [] this. Now how can I display this in the selectbox for states?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49533/discussion-between-anurupr-and-jerielle)

Answer (score 0):

you must return a JSON object in the controller like this

```
public function get_provinces(){

 $id = $this->input->post('id');
 $country = $this->alliance_model->hhj_provinces($id);
 $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
 $this->output->set_output(json_encode( $country));
```

}

then in the View

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: var_country_selection,
        data: { id: $(this).val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
           $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                     console.log(value.field)

        }
    });
```